# kendoUi mvc grid, custom binding to datasource object

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have this code, I want to add new line of data to a grid, so i get the grid datasource, and add the json object to the datasource object. I want to just rebind the grid without making a new request. When i use the sync(); it makes a request to my controller..
I remember in the old telerik mvc grid, there was a rebind() method.

```
var grid = $("#AGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
grid.add(data.newlIne);
grid.sync();
```

Ok the new item is being added to the grid, but the item is not being shown, i think it might be CSS problem.

Comment: Why you need to rebind it? It should automatically add the item to the grid. You use `sync` for sending modification to the server.

Comment: @OnaBai it does not appear when i just use the add method...

Comment: Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/mrujV/ BTW: did you set your Grid as editable `editable: true`?

Comment: @OnaBai Ok the new item is being added to the grid, but the item is not being shown, i think it might be CSS problem. The grid is not re-rendering with the new items.

Comment: In my example the new item is showing, isn't it? Could you add some information into your original post showing the grid initialization or a JS Fiddle were we can see what you mean?